# Freezing row headers in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, header, ssrs-2008

I know this seems like a duplicate question, but for some reason I can't get it to work.

In my matrix, I'm trying to **freeze my row headers** so when I scroll right I can still see them.

I've tried clicking the small arrow to go into `advanced mode` and set `FixedData` to `True` on the top most static property, but that didn't work.

I've also tried right clicking the tablix, going into the properties and checking `keep header visible while scrolling`, and I still get the same error.

The exact error says,

> "The table "matrix1" includes a table header or column with
>   FixedHeader set to true. This is not allowed on data regions inside
>   other data regions."

- What does this error mean exactly?
- Am I setting the wrong property to True?
- Do I need to create another row or column?

This has been bugging me for awhile, and any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you include your report design?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. It says I don't have enough reputation for it. Can I freeze a field name in the report?

Comment: 1. Is there another table inside your matrix? 2. Also you can upload an image at imgur or dropbox and give a link here.

Comment: Yes, there is another table in the report. Could that be what's affecting the matrix?

Comment: Is it inside the matrix or independent of matrix? Also is there a list also?

Comment: Is independent of the matrix, but can be put inside if necessary, and there is no list.

Comment: Are you able to upload your design to imgur and provide the link?